# divide based on row without multiple queries

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table with 3 columns, ID, Line number, Total.
I want to divide total $ of line number 5 by line number 3 based on ID in a single access query

Starting point is

```
ID Line Amount
1 | 5 | 4
1 | 3 | 2
2 | 5 | 6
2 | 3 | 2
3 | 5 | 16
3 | 3 | 4
```

to

```
ID Ratio
1 | 2
2 | 3
3 | 4
```

I can create a table with ID, Line#5, and total, then another table with line#3 where the ID are both unique, join them then divide, but I feel like there must be an easier way.

I'm using MS Access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select id,
       (max(iif(linenumber = 5, total, null)) /
        max(iif(linenumber = 3, total, null)
       )
from t
group by id;
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I'm looking for a different solution. I rephrased the question and added example of result to make it more clear.

Comment: @ArchavanichKawmongkolsi . . . It is basically the same query with `group by`.

Comment: Thanks, this is amazing!

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
  t3.id,
  t5.total / t3.total
FROM
  Data t3
  inner join Data t5 on t3.id = t5.id
WHERE 
  t3.line_number = 3
  and t5.line_number = 5
```

Result:

```
id  Ratio
1   2
2   3
3   4
4   5
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/518a4/5/0

Comment: Would this still make sense if there's 10 different line numbers and 5 different sets of ratios? or is it better practice to create 5 of these and union by ID

Comment: @ArchavanichKawmongkolsi - it depends what the rule is. Your stated rule in the question is "line number 5 divided by line number 3". Can you generalise that rule? If you can generalise it, a better query might be possible. If the line numbers are known/fixed then you could union several select statements also.

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.id, t1.amount/t2.amount as ratio
from t t1
join t t2 on t1.id = t2.id
where t1.line = 5
and t2.line = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this. In the where clause you must check the value of `line 3` is not equal to `0`. since this will give you error on runtime.

```
select t5 .id , t5.total/t3.total as Ratio
from table as t5 
     inner join table as t3 
     on t5.id=t3.id and t5.line=5 and t3.line=3
where isnull(t3.total,0)>0
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that you state:

> I want to divide **total** $ of line number 5 by line number 3 based on ID in a single access query.

Assuming that there is a possibility of *multiple* records with `line = 3` or `line = 5` for a given `ID` value, you could use the following to sum the `Amount` associated with each `Line` value (3 or 5), and then perform the division of the totals obtained for each `ID` group:

```
select t.id, sum(iif(t.line=5,t.amount,0))/sum(iif(t.line=3,t.amount,0)) as ratio
from YourTable t
group by t.id
```

I'm unsure how you wish to handle the scenario where either there is no record with `Line = 3` for a given `ID`, or where `Amount = 0` for `Line = 3` - both will result in a Div/0 error.